# Sync data from sql server to postgresql database in Java

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, change-tracking, change-data-capture

I coded a java server synchronize data from oracle database to postgresql database used a technology name Oracle DCN.
Now I want do a sync like it but to use sql server to postgresql.
Noted sql server provided change tracking and Change Data Capture to do it.
But I wonder if it can be down with java and how?